# Can you pass an objects method as a callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, object, methods, callback

So I have an object lets call it A with a sub object which I'll call B which has a method/function called "CallMe" which I wish to be called when and object loads but I can't seem to get it to work. Is it even possible?

Example:

```
var A = {
  B: {
    CallMe: function() {
      alert('I\'ve been Called!');
    }
  }
}

var objImage = new Image();
objImage.onLoad = A.B.CallMe;
objImage.src = '/img/some_image.png';
```

Comment: take note that CallMe will be executed in the context of objImage and not A.B . Therefore, the keyword this in CallMe will refer to objImage during the callback

Comment: @BiAiB Is there no way to have this refer to the methods parent rather than the caller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should bind it to `.onload` property not `.onLoad` - this should fix it, silly typo - such are the worst

Comment: I though it might be something stupid like I had written the method name wrong, it's obviously been a long day. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine... you just need to need to call it (objImage.onLoad();):

```
var A = {
  B: {
    CallMe: function() {
      alert('I\'ve been Called!');
    }
  }
}

var Image = function(){

}
Image.prototype.onLoad = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var objImage = new Image();
    objImage.onLoad = A.B.CallMe;

    objImage.onLoad();
});
```

Test code here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/yAJfd/1/

Comment: The point of `onload` is that you *don't* need to call it explicitly. It should respond to the load event of the image.

Comment: Ooops, my bad. then what he wants is to bind to an event listener?

Comment: Yes, an image has an `onload` you can bind to that fires the handler when the image finishes loading.